# How can use pandas group-by while adding new columns on a single level?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, grouping

The original data looks like this:

```
    Date        E   
0   2017-09-01  -   
1   2017-09-01  +   
2   2017-09-01  +   
3   2017-09-01  +  
...
...
```

After applying groupby:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'E'])['Date'].count().to_frame(name = 'Count').reset_index()
```

I get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Date        E   Count
0   2017-09-01  +   11
1   2017-09-01  -   1
2   2017-09-04  +   1
3   2017-09-04  -   7
4   2017-09-05  +   1
5   2017-09-05  -   23
```

How can I transform this into a dataframe that instead looks like this:

```
    Date        +   -
0   2017-09-01  11  1
2   2017-09-04  1   7
4   2017-09-05  1   23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think better is use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), because [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) is used for count non `NaN` values.

Then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'E'])['Date'].size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
E        Date  +  -
0  2017-09-01  3  1
```

Less typing solution, but in larger df slowier is [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['E'])
print (df)
E           +  -
Date            
2017-09-01  3  1
```

Answer (score 4):

Or, use `pd.crosstab`

```
In [1736]: pd.crosstab(df.Date, df.E)
Out[1736]:
E           +  -
Date
2017-09-01  3  1
2017-09-02  1  0
```

Or, `pivot_table`

```
In [1737]: pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date'], columns=['E'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[1737]:
E           +  -
Date
2017-09-01  3  1
2017-09-02  1  0
```